# Camera acts weird in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

https://streamable.com/jexe9a
See it for yourself. Please someone help!

I didn't try anything (I don't know how to reset my view, I'm a beginner), I just restarted Unity and nothing changed. I want my camera to be able to move normally.

Answer (score 1):

Right-Click the Axis-Gizmo and enable "Perspective" to turn off the orthographic projection. Or just press the "ISO" Text below the Axis-Gizmo to toggle the view mode.

[image]

If geometry keeps vanishing, adjust the clipping planes:[image]

You could also select an object and press **F** to focus the object, which would also adjust the clipping planes if you have "Dynamic Clipping" active.

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally put the view in orthographic mode - click on the "ISO" button in the top right, below the colorful 3D axis labels to get back to perspective view.